# Как вложить scroll внутрь элемента

Tags: css

При наведении на `td` появляется скролл, помогите сделать чтобы этот скролл был внутри `td` и не хватал себе отдельную высоту.

```css
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td {
  max-width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #d4d7db;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  border-spacing: 0px;
}

td:hover {
  overflow-x: auto;
}
```

```html
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit. Magni, aliquam!</td>
        <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit. Magni, aliquam!</td>
  <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit. Magni, aliquam!</td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Зачем Вы изменили код в вопросе после того, как дали ответ? Теперь ответ не имеет смысла, так?

Comment: @UModeL, ну я думал перефразировать вопрос, на тему от количества текста, потом начал с js'ом играться и забыл дописать вопрос. В общем сейчас обратно изменю как было, а потом если что новый вопрос задам, т.к. это уже другой вопрос) ещё раз спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Будьте внимательны - в разных браузерах, а также при изменении стилей скроллбаров, может понадобиться корректировка padding-ов. Чтобы вычислялось само - только скрипты.

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; }

td {
  max-width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #d4d7db;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  padding: 17px 5px 17px;
}
td:hover {
  overflow-x: auto;
  padding: 17px 5px 0px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit. Magni, aliquam!</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit. Magni, aliquam!</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit. Magni, aliquam!</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Ещё "костыль", если текста в ячейке мало:

```css
table { border-collapse: collapse; }

td {
  max-width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #d4d7db;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  border-spacing: 0px;
  padding: 17px 5px 17px;
}
td:hover {
  overflow-x: scroll;
  padding: 17px 5px 0px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Lorem</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit. Magni, aliquam!</td>
    <td>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet elit. Magni, aliquam!</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: то что нужно, спасибо

Comment: я понял о чём вы когда вставил меньше теста, а про другие браузеры это уже потом думать буду))

Comment: спасибо, я это уже попробовал, но как-то не красиво получается

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй поставить - overflow-x: scroll;

Comment: это не сработает

Comment: но я всё же взял и убедился, что это не сработает)

Comment: @YobaFighter что тебе именно нужно? Чтобы скролл был постоянно или как?

Comment: @YobaFighter Я так понял у вас Firefox? На Chrome отлично работает

Comment: мне нужно чтобы высоту дополнительную скролл не пихал. @UModeL сделал то что нужно

Comment: @YobaFighter если добавишь transition к коду - будет капец.

Comment: @w3cwhy, куда именно его добавить?))

Answer (score 0):

Надо было просто подробнее изучить свойства:

overflow-x: overlay;